# AES-256 encryption in PHP

Tags: php, security, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I need a PHP function, `AES256_encode($dataToEcrypt)` to encrypt the `$data` into AES-256 and another one `AES256_decode($encryptedData)` do the opposite. Does anyone know what code should this functions have?

Comment: Here is a good blog post explaining how to work with MCrypt library: http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-use-mcrypt-library-in-php/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look at the [mcrypt module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

AES-Rijndael example taken from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
# show key size use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192
# and 256 respectively
$key_size =  strlen($key);
echo "Key size: " . $key_size . "\n";
$text = "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.";
echo strlen($text) . "\n";

$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
echo strlen($crypttext) . "\n";
```

This is the [decrypt function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

Comment: Yes, there are even examples on this page of how to encrypt/decrypt AES: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I thought RIJNDAEL and AES were two different algorithms.

Comment: -1, AES-256 is **different** from `RIJNDAEL-256`. The 256 in `AES` refers to the *key* size, where the 256 in `RIJNDAEL` refers to block size. `AES-256` is `RIJNDAEL-128` when used with a 256 bit key.

Comment: -1 it's bad in several ways: 1) It doesn't use AES (see ircmaxell's comment) 2) It uses ECB 3) It doesn't include a MAC and thus is vulnerable to active attacks. 4) It uses a password as key. Either use a random key, or use properly hashed password. 5) It's better to use `/dev/urandrom` to generate the iv (simply pass `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` to `create_iv`)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've edited the answer according to your observations. Now the answer should be correct.

Comment: I just want to emphasize that MACs are really important if active attacks are possible. A well known attack is the ["padding oracle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) where the reaction of the recipient leaks information about the plaintext allowing byte-by-byte recovery of the plaintext by querying the recipient.

Comment: Padding is also important to note: as the mcrypt library in php only supports zero length padding. Where as most people using pkcs#5 or pkcs#7 padding. So always make sure you match the padding up if encrypting and decrypting in different platforms/places (for example: webserver vs mobile app)

Comment: PHP has deprecated `mcrypt` library, it will be removed from PHP version after 7.1. As such, using suggesting mcrypt makes this answer deprecated. See http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php

Answer (score 19):

> I need a PHP function, `AES256_encode($dataToEcrypt)` to encrypt the `$data` into AES-256 and another one `AES256_decode($encryptedData)` do the opposite. Does anyone know what code should this functions have?

There is a [difference between encrypting and encoding](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

Do you *really* need AES-256? The security of AES-256 versus AES-128 isn't that significant; you're more likely to screw up at the protocol layer than get hacked because you used a 128-bit block cipher instead of a 256-bit block cipher.

### Important - Use A Library

[image: A flowchart for PHP users]

- [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption)
- [PECL libsodium](https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium)
- [Halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite) (libsodium wrapper, now stable)

#### A Quick and Dirty AES-256 Implementation

If you're interested in building your own **not for the sake of deploying it in production** but rather for the sake of your own education, I've included a sample AES256

```
/**
 * This is a quick and dirty proof of concept for StackOverflow.
 * 
 * @ref http://stackoverflow.com/q/6770370/2224584
 * 
 * Do not use this in production.
 */
abstract class ExperimentalAES256DoNotActuallyUse
{
    /**
     * Encrypt with AES-256-CTR + HMAC-SHA-512
     * 
     * @param string $plaintext Your message
     * @param string $encryptionKey Key for encryption
     * @param string $macKey Key for calculating the MAC
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encrypt($plaintext, $encryptionKey, $macKey)
    {
        $nonce = random_bytes(16);
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
            $plaintext,
            'aes-256-ctr',
            $encryptionKey,
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
            $nonce
        );
        $mac = hash_hmac('sha512', $nonce.$ciphertext, $macKey, true);
        return base64_encode($mac.$nonce.$ciphertext);
    }

    /**
     * Verify HMAC-SHA-512 then decrypt AES-256-CTR
     * 
     * @param string $message Encrypted message
     * @param string $encryptionKey Key for encryption
     * @param string $macKey Key for calculating the MAC
     */
    public static function decrypt($message, $encryptionKey, $macKey)
    {
        $decoded = base64_decode($message);
        $mac = mb_substr($message, 0, 64, '8bit');
        $nonce = mb_substr($message, 64, 16, '8bit');
        $ciphertext = mb_substr($message, 80, null, '8bit');

        $calc = hash_hmac('sha512', $nonce.$ciphertext, $macKey, true);
        if (!hash_equals($calc, $mac)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid MAC');
        }
        return openssl_decrypt(
            $ciphertext,
            'aes-256-ctr',
            $encryptionKey,
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
            $nonce
        );
    }
}
```

#### Usage

First, generate two keys (yes, two of them) and store them somehow.

```
$eKey = random_bytes(32);
$aKey = random_bytes(32);
```

Then to encrypt/decrypt messages:

```
$plaintext = 'This is just a test message.';
$encrypted = ExperimentalAES256DoNotActuallyUse::encrypt($plaintext, $eKey, $aKey);
$decrypted = ExperimentalAES256DoNotActuallyUse::decrypt($encrypted, $eKey, $aKey);
```

If you don't have `random_bytes()`, get [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Comment: Can you explain why it would not be a good idea to use the quick-and-dirty implementation in production if it does what is needed?

Comment: You'll find that you want [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) rather than rolling your own or copying and pasting from StackOverflow. The only reason to roll your own is to create toy implementations to teach yourself.

Comment: Yes, but say for example I wanted to handle something like stream ciphering from CPP over a socket to PHP. I've not personally looked into defuse's library, but is there a reason the generic AES256 written above wouldn't be suitable? Clearly not the exact code, but something similar as far as building the cipher.

Comment: is this answer still up to date?  (Just checking).  I do not know the history of halite, but it seems to me that there is currently stable version of `v3.2.0` that's available

Comment: Nothing has changed, except libsodium is due to land in PHP 7.2.

Comment: What is "$ciphertext" in "decrypt" method

Comment: @ScottArciszewski, The other reason would be "not renting whole building just to store a piece of paper".

Answer (score 17):

**MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256** is not equivalent to AES_256.

The way to make RIJNDAEL be decrypted from AES is to use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 and padd the string to encrypt before encrypting

AES-256 has BlockSize=128bit and KeySize=256bit
Rijndael-256 has BlockSize=256bit and KeySize=256bit

Just AES/Rijndael 128bit are identical.
Rijndael-192 and Rijndael-256 are not identical to AES-192 and AES-256 (block sizes and number of rounds differ).

Comment: You're certainly correct, but this post doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @CodesInChaos. The way to make RIJNDAEL be decrypted from AES with openssl is to use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 and padd the string to encrypt before encrypting with the follwing function:

<?php
function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) {
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
?>

Answer (score -2):

```
$key = '324325923495kdfgiert734t'; // key used for decryption in jasper code
$text = 'string_to_be_encrypted';
$encrypted = fnEncrypt($text, $key);




function fnEncrypt( $plaintext, $key )
{
$plaintext = pkcs5_pad($plaintext, 16);

return bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, hex2bin($key), $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

}


function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
$pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}



function hex2bin($hexdata) 
{
$bindata = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) 
    {
      $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
    }

return $bindata;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.

Comment: Kindly add the decrypt function also.