# PHP data security help using functions

Tags: php, database, security, encryption, database-security

Is storing emails in databases encrypted using encrypt() function in php secure ? If yes then how can i decrypt it if not then what's a better idea ?  example : crypt() function

Comment: Define "secure"; it depends where you store the key, etc.!  Also, what is the encrypt() function?

Comment: it's the crypt() function

Comment: `crypt()` is not an encryption function, it's a hashing function.  It cannot be reversed.  Any of the real encryption functions will either have equivalent decryption functions (e.g. `mcrypt_encrypt`/`mcrypt_decrypt`), or will take a parameter to specify whether they should encrypt or decrypt.

Comment: so what do you suggest , a secure way for encrypting using encrypt functions in php ?

Answer (score 1):

The best you're going to get is with a [Rijndael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption. What you're doing is **hashing** which isn't reversible.

Check this out for AES encryption in PHP:

[AES-256 encryption in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770370/aes-256-encryption-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

A good option to look at is PGP

You can find more info about this by clicking [here](http://devzone.zend.com/30/encryption-and-decryption-using-php-and-gnupg/)