# PHP with mysql fails to decrypt a string (string comes from the database)

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am not seeing this addressed here (mysql is key - not just a encrypt/decrypt question).

The same php code decrypts  successfully a md5 encrypted string when it does NOT come from the mysql database. Not using  mysql a string both encrypts and decrypts successfully.  I use the same decrypt code in both scenarios.

1 )string is encrypted and saved into mysql

2) encrypted string is later pulled out and attempted to be decrypted and displayed.

3) mysql version - decryption fails (outputs -> ef32b9252e40bc9e228744923e33393b). Not using  mysql – (outputs “team”)

```
<?php
// version #1 – mysql version
$encrypted = "team";

// encrypt the string $encrypted
$key = md5(date('l jS of F Y h i s A'));
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));**

// Of course here would be the INSERT…..
// So now “team” is in the mysql database encrypted.

$userid = "bob";
$query = "select team from league where username = '".$userid."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $encrypted = trim($row['team']);
}

// decrypt the string $encrypted
$key = md5(date('l jS of F Y h i s A'));
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

print  $decrypted;   //outputs -> ef32b9252e40bc9e228744923e33393b

// Version #2 - non mysql

$encrypted  = "team"    // Not from mysql DB.

// encrypt the string $encrypted
$key = md5(date('l jS of F Y h i s A'));
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

// decrypt the string $encrypted
$key = md5(date('l jS of F Y h i s A'));
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

print  $decrypted;   //outputs -> team
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the issue is with your use of `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`.

From [AES-256 encryption in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770370/aes-256-encryption-in-php#comment24999745_6770394)

> AES-256 is different from RIJNDAEL-256. The 256 in AES refers to the key size, where the 256 in RIJNDAEL refers to block size. AES-256 is RIJNDAEL-128 when used with a 256 bit key.